# Set Cookies for URL Connection Android

Tags: android, urlconnection

I need to set Cookies for URL connection. I am new to Android. In iphone it is done as below:

```
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<Server URL>"];

NSHTTPCookie *usernamecookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:
                                   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [serverURL host], NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                   [serverURL path], NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                     @"username", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                     @"<username>", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                     nil]];

NSHTTPCookie *passwordcookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:
                                   [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [serverURL host], NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                   [serverURL path], NSHTTPCookiePath,
                                     @"password", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                     @"<password>", NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                      nil]];

[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:usernamecookie];
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookie:passwordcookie];

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:serverURL] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *response = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSLog(@"response data %@",[response description]);
```

Kindly help if anybody any idea about that.

Answer (score 3):

Android has something very similar. You create cookies and add them to the cookie storage, and they are then available when requested by a server in an HTTP connection.

To create and add a cookie use the following code:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("lang", "fr");
cookie.setDomain("twitter.com");
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setVersion(0);
cookieManager.getCookieStore().add(new URI("http://twitter.com/"), cookie);
```

For more information, see [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html)

Comment: Thanks. Let me check and try.